# Yamaha MIDI/USB driver on Linux

Tags: midi, usb

I have a Yamaha keyboard (a PSR-3000, to be exact), which I would like to connect as a MIDI device to a Linux computer (a Raspberry Pi with Raspbian). It shows up in `lsusb` as:

> Bus 001 Device 068: ID 0499:102b Yamaha Corp. PSR-3000

Therefore, what I do need is a MIDI/USB driver such as one on the official Yamaha website. Does anybody know if such a driver exists for Linux, and if so, where I can find it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this to work a reboot is required; then a special device `/dev/midi1` will appear.

Comment: Doesn't loading the `snd-usb-audio` module work?

Comment: @CL. Maybe, but I didn't have to try.

Answer (score 1):

I have two Yamaha keyboards connected to a Raspberry Pi zero 2W, one keyboard through an UNO USB Midi interface and one through Yamaha's UX16 interface.  Just plug the synthesizer in through whatever USB-Midi interface you have and use aplaymidi -l to list the recognized Midi devices.  It should list your device with a "Port" number on the left, which will be something like 20:0.  You don't need the :0 but you can use the port number (20 in this example) in a command to play a Midi file.  If you have a file named "song.mid" in your main directory, using this example, enter:

aplaymidi -p 10 /home/pi/song.mid

I don't see any reason to reboot to get this.  Also, neither the Uno nor the Ux16 needed a driver downloaded.  They worked as soon as I plugged them in.